# Unable to load Bootstrap 4.2.1 styles In Angular 7 project

Tags: angular, google-apps-script, angular7, google-contacts-api, angular-cli-v7

I have added bootstrap to Angular Project using:

```
npm install --popper.js
npm install --jquery.js
npm install --bootstrap
```

--> It is added in the angular.json file as:

```
"styles": [
"src/assets/css/styles.css",
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
]
```

and also in package.json as:

```
"dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^4.2.1"
}
```

But my bootstrap classes like `.btn .btn-primary, .form-group, .form-control` are not working. Please help me with this. As our project is complex and needed to be loaded faster, please suggest me a solution that doesn't take longer loading time. (That means without imports/plugins inside the html or css files)

Comment: Why are  [tag:google-apps-script] and [tag:google-contacts] here?

Answer (score 0):

Just check in **angular.json** have you added these lines or not.

```
"styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        ]
```

**Export bootstarp in app module**

app.module.ts

```
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```